# No of threads using epoll

Tags: linux, multithreading, epoll

Let's say I have a high performance server application that's running 50 threads where each of those threads is listening for data on 1000 sockets using `epoll()`. When some data comes on a socket the thread processes it. Assume that this processing is very very fast i.e. does not block much. As a result all 50 threads can scale pretty well. Given this situation, I've heard that if I were to go in and reduce the number of threads to 5 (i.e. make the 1/10th) and increase the sockets per thread to 10000 (i.e. make them 10 times) the system would be faster overall although the number of connections remains the same. I'm imagining this happens because when the number of threads is reduced by 1/10th the number of context switches and the chance of CPU caches getting stale is significantly reduced which results in the speed-up.

However, what I'm wondering if this will really help.

I'm concerned about how other threads in the system outside of this particular application will influence the picture. I'm assuming all threads, regardless of in which process they are, compete with each other for the CPUs from the scheduler's point of view. If the total threads in the system in the first scenario where 1050 and after my change they come down to 1005, it doesn't change much system wide. You still have roughly similar number of threads competing for the CPUs. So in this case my application won't benefit much. My question is is my thinking correct? In other words whenever you talk about number of threads in an `epoll()` based application you shouldn't be thinking of total threads in the system not just the application you're concerned with?

Comment: Your question is quite broad. At first look, the question is really can 5 thread handle 10000 sockets each better than 50 threads manage 1000 each? That's just a "have to test" issue. The broader system issue is if you are being asked to investigate reducing your 50 to 5 out of 1050 - and then other 20 apps with 50 threads each are asked to reduce to 5 each, then if it works the system count is reduced from 1050 to 105 -- and than can system wide benefit. See what others have to say, but whether it impacts your app depends on the result of 50-5 testing.

Comment: It's not about the number of total threads, but the number of ready/runnable threads.  Whenever there are more threads runnable than cores, the task scheduler has to preempt and context switch them, which comes at a cost.

Comment: I think wasn't very clear in asking the precise question. My question is: does advice like "reducing the number of threads will help your app's performance" make any sense at all in the absence of a consideration for total number of threads in the rest of the system (which, to be more precise, should actually be total number of _runnable_ threads as Ben said above). I mean is it even worth focusing on reducing threads in my app if I can't predict the total load on the scheduler system-wide? Or, put another way, would you say the above advice is good advice in general or most of time?

Comment: Is this server going to be dedicated to mainly running your application, so that you can assume that not much else will be going on most of the time?  Or will this server be running on a general-purpose OS, such that you can't make any assumptions about what other programs might or might not be doing when your program is in use?  (and if it's the latter, then perhaps one performance enhancement to consider would be moving your program over to dedicated hardware)

Comment: Why would you do this? Why not drop to five threads but let any thread service any socket? Why map sockets to threads in a static way that forces the system to do a needless context switch if the "wrong" thread is running?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Currently there's no telling whether the app will run on a dedicated machine or not. We can surely recommend it but can't guarantee this is how it'll be deployed in production. But anyway what you're saying kinda answers my question because you imply that it _does_ matter how many other threads are there in other processes and therefore you _have_ to consider the wider context before making a change like I mentioned above (i.e. going from 50 to 5 threads).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Probably something I should have mentioned - these are going to be long-lived connections not just a one-off exchange between the client and the server. Therefore, the design is that the main thread that's listening for new connections does the `accept()` and hands over the new socket to one of the 50 worker threads. The worker thread than has to do `epoll()` over all such connections it's currently responsible for. So I believe we have no option but have dedicated threads each listening on a set of connections and next thread dedicated to listening to the next set and so on.

Comment: @FrederickTheFool That seems like bad design. What if lots of high load connections happen to get the same thread? Better design: One epoll set, all connections go into it. Every thread either waits on a condition variable (if another thread is blocked in epoll and no sockets waiting for service), calls epoll (if no sockets waiting for service and no thread already blocked in epoll) or services whichever sockets are waiting for service. This avoids that problem and avoids unnecessary context switches if the "wrong" thread happens to be running since any thread can now service any connection.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I see what you're saying. But this is legacy code base which I've inherited. Not sure if I'm allowed to change the fundamental design. But I'll definitely keep your suggestion in mind. Just to confirm what you're saying is: a. Have a single epoll statement with all sockets in it. b. Wrap this statement in a lock+condition variable. c. Have all worker threads wait on this lock/condvar. d. when a thread is gets signaled it enters the epoll and waits on it. e. Whenever it comes out of epoll it signals the next thread and itself goes off to process the data.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Not quite. That would slow socket discovery and add system calls. When a thread calls `epoll`, it adds all the sockets that need work to a queue. A thread blocks on `epoll` only if that queue is empty. If it puts more sockets in the queue, it unblocks the condition variable to let the pool of threads empty the queue. The thread that first finds an empty queue blocks on `epoll`, the others on the condition variable.

Comment: Got it. Makes sense. Thanks for sharing this approach David.